# How to copy an element of std::variant to a variable of another variant-type

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

This is a followup on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073751/3876684).
Assume we have two types of [`std:variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) with partly the same member types. For instance if we have

```
struct Monday {};
struct Tuesday {};
/* ... etc. */
using WeekDay= std::variant<Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday>;
using Working_Day= std::variant<Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday>;
```

`Working_Day` is a sub-type of `WeekDay`. Now how can we copy a variable of one type to a variable of the other type? If all type members of the source are type members of the target a conversion function can be defined as

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To var2var( From && from )
{
    return std::visit(
        []( auto && elem ) { return To( std::forward<decltype(elem)>( elem ) ); },
        std::forward<From>( from ) );
}
```

It can be used as

```
Working_Day  d1= Tuesday{};
WeekDay      d2= var2var<WeekDay>( d1 );
```

Trying this the other way around, i.e. casting a `WeekDay` into a `Working_Day`, results in a compile time error. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the requirement is that if the type isn't present in the target variant, throw an exception. We can do that by introducing a new type which is only *exactly* convertible to a specific target:

```
template <typename T>
struct Exactly {
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>, int> = 0>
    operator U() const;
};
```

And then use that to either construct or throw:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To unsafe_variant_cast(From && from)
{
    return std::visit([](auto&& elem) -> To {
        using U = std::decay_t<decltype(elem)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<To, Exactly<U>>) {
            return To(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem));
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad type");
        }
    }, std::forward<From>(from));
}
```

Note that you need to explicitly provide a return type because otherwise in the exceptional case, it would get deduced to `void` and the visitors wouldn't all have the same return type.

The use of `Exactly<U>` as opposed to just `decltype(elem)` means that casting a `variant<int>` to a `variant<unsigned int>` will throw instead of succeeding. If the intend is to have it succeed, you can use `decltype(elem)` instead.

---

An alternative here would be to use [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_containsl_v), in which everything template metaprogramming related is a one-liner. This is also a more direct check:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To unsafe_variant_cast(From && from)
{
    return std::visit([](auto&& elem) -> To {
        using U = std::decay_t<decltype(elem)>;
        if constexpr (mp_contains<To, U>::value) {
            return To(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem));
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad type");
        }
    }, std::forward<From>(from));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the example above does not work is that [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) requires `operator()` of the submitted functional object to be overloaded for each type member of the source `variant`. But for some of these types there is no matching constructor of the target `variant`.

The solution is to treat visiting differently for types which both `variants` have in common and those which are members of the source `variant` only.

```
template <class To, class From>
To var2var( From && from ) 
{
    using FRM= std::remove_reference_t<From>;
    using TO=  std::remove_reference_t<To>;
    using common_types= typename split_types<TO, FRM>::common_types;
    using single_types= typename split_types<TO, FRM>::single_types;
    return std::visit(
        conversion_visitor<TO, common_types, single_types>(),
        std::forward<From>( from ) );
}
```

Here `std::visit` gets an object of `struct conversion_visitor`. The latter takes template parameters `common_types` and `single_types`, which contain the type members of the source `variant` split in the mentioned way.

```
template<class... T> struct type_list {};

template <class To, class V1, class V2>
struct conversion_visitor;

template <class To, class... CT, class... ST>
struct conversion_visitor< To, type_list<CT...>, type_list<ST...> > 
: public gen_variant<To, CT>...
, public not_gen_variant<To, ST>...
{
    using gen_variant<To,CT>::operator()...;
    using not_gen_variant<To,ST>::operator()...;
};
```

`type_list` is a container for types, which we use here because a `variant` cannot be empty. `conversion_visitor` is derived from structs `gen_variant` and `not_gen_variant` which both overload `operator()`.

```
template<class To, class T>
struct gen_variant
{
    To operator()( T const & elem ) { return To( elem ); }
    To operator()( T && elem ) { return To( std::forward<T>( elem ) ); }
};

template<class To, class T>
struct not_gen_variant
{
    To operator()( T const & ) { throw std::runtime_error("Type of element in source variant is no type member of target variant"); }
};
```

`not_gen_variant` is meant to treat the *error cases*, i.e. the cases in which the source contains a variable of a type which is not a member of the target `variant`. It throws in this example. Alternatively it could return a [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) if that is contained in the target `variant`.

With these definitions `std::visit` will call `conversion_visitor::operator()`. If the variable stored in the source has a type which the target can handle, that call is forwarded to `gen_variant::operator()`. Otherwise it is forwarded to `not_gen_variant::operator()`.  `gen_variant::operator()` just calls the constructor of the target `variant` with the source element as argument.

What is left is to describe how to obtain `common_types` and `single_types` using `struct split_types`.

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct split_types;

template<class... To, class... From>
struct split_types< std::variant<To...>, std::variant<From...> >
{
    using to_tl=   type_list<std::remove_reference_t<To>...>;
    using from_tl= type_list<std::remove_reference_t<From>...>;
    using common_types= typename split_types_h<to_tl, from_tl, type_list<>, type_list<> >::common_types;
    using single_types= typename split_types_h<to_tl, from_tl, type_list<>, type_list<> >::single_types;
};
```

`split_types` takes the target and the source `variant` as template parameters. It first puts the members of those `variants` into `type_list`s `to_tl` and `from_tl`. These are forwarded to a helper `split_types_h`. Here the two empty `type_list`s will be filled up with the common and the single types as follows.

```
template<class T1, class T2, bool>
struct append_if;

template<class... Ts, class T>
struct append_if< type_list<Ts...>, T, true >
{
  using type= type_list< Ts..., T >;
};

template<class... Ts, class T>
struct append_if< type_list<Ts...>, T, false >
{
  using type= type_list< Ts... >;
};

template<class T1, class T2, bool b>
using append_if_t= typename append_if<T1, T2, b>::type;


template<class T1, class T2, class CT, class ST >
struct split_types_h;

template<class... T1, class... CT, class... ST>
struct split_types_h< type_list<T1...>, type_list<>, type_list<CT...>, type_list<ST...> >
{
    using common_types= type_list<CT...>;
    using single_types= type_list<ST...>;
};

template<class... T1, class T2f, class... T2, class... CT, class... ST>
struct split_types_h< type_list<T1...>, type_list<T2f,T2...>, type_list<CT...>, type_list<ST...> >
{
    enum : bool { contains= (std::is_same_v<T2f,T1> || ...) };
    using c_types_h= append_if_t<type_list<CT...>, T2f,  contains>;
    using s_types_h= append_if_t<type_list<ST...>, T2f, !contains>;
    using common_types= typename split_types_h<type_list<T1...>, type_list<T2...>, c_types_h, s_types_h>::common_types;
    using single_types= typename split_types_h<type_list<T1...>, type_list<T2...>, c_types_h, s_types_h>::single_types;
};
```

`split_types_h` takes one type member of the source (`type_list<T2f,T2...>`) after the other and checks if the target also `contains` it. If so the type (`T2f`) is appended to `common_types` (with the help of `c_types_h`). Otherwise it is appended to `single_types`.

The casting function can be used as follows ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FRmLoitheLqK8Sbb)).

```
Working_Day  d1= Tuesday{};
Working_Day  d2= d1;
WeekDay      d3= Saturday{};

d3= var2var<WeekDay>( d1 );
d2= var2var<Working_Day>( d3 );
d2= var2var<Working_Day>( d1 );
try
{
    WeekDay d4= Sunday{};
    d1= var2var<Working_Day>( d4 );
}
catch( std::runtime_error & err )
{
    std::cerr << "Runtime error caught: " << err.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Nice, but a very complex way to detect "types that can be converted to a std variant".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that not all types in the source variant are handled by the destination.

We can fix this.

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overloaded : Fs... {
  using Fs::operator()...;
};
template<class...Fs>
overloaded(Fs&&...)->overloaded<std::decay_t<Fs>...>;
```

this is a helper that lets us pass around lambda or function overloads.

```
template<class To, class From>
To var2var( From && from )
{
  return std::visit(
    overloaded{
      []( To elem ) { return elem; },
      []( auto&& x )
      ->std::enable_if_t< !std::is_convertible<decltype(x), To>{}, To> {
        throw std::runtime_error("wrong type");
      }
    },
    std::forward<From>( from )
  );
}
```

now that SFINAE is a mess.  Let us hide it.

```
template<class F, class Otherwise>
auto call_or_otherwise( F&& f, Otherwise&& o ) {
  return overloaded{
    std::forward<F>(f),
    [o = std::forward<Otherwise>(o)](auto&&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t< !std::is_invocable< F&, decltype(args)... >{}, std::invoke_result< Otherwise const&, decltype(args)... > >
    { return o( decltype(args)(args)... ); }
  };
}

template<class To, class From>
To var2var( From && from )
{
  return std::visit(
    call_or_otherwise(
        [](To to){ return to; },
        [](auto&&)->To{ throw std::runtime_error("type mismatch"); }
    ),
    std::forward<From>(from)
  );
}
```

`call_or_otherwise` takes 2 lambdas (or other callables), and returns one a callable that dispatches to the first if possible, and only falls back on the second if the first fails.

Comment: Worth noting that is slightly different as it allows a successful cast from, e.g., `variant<int>` to `variant<unsigned int>`.